# facing problems with my android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm new to android developing, and when I finally sit down to learn, my android emulator wouldn't run. Well, some button is tellimg me the AVD: Nexus_5_API_23_x86 is running, but I don't get any emulator screen popping up even after leaving my laptop in overnight. 
it's the first time I'm running the emulator, and the emulator screen has never appeared before.
Also, I always get this message displayed:
C:\Users\HUBERT\Application\Local1\Android\sdk1\Tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_ 5_API_23_x86
Also, if I click to run an app, I get the device chooser pop up, I select the Nexus and hit OK, but nothing happens. I still don't get the emulator screen.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the adv manager to get something that will work on your laptop. On the second bar down, the one under your "file, edit, view bar..., select the AVD manager.  It's the third icon from the "?" icon traveling left.  Try x86 and arm setups to see what will work. remember that the initial load will take some time.  2-3 minutes with 4 gig of RAM.  what OS and how much RAM do you have?

Comment: I'm using Windows 8 and I'm having a 4gig RAM. the default nexus is using a x86 CPU and is using I gb/1024mb just as the Intel haxm

Comment: how was that selected as best answer?

Comment: I'm using Windows 8 and I'm having a 4gig RAM.
the default nexus is using a x86 CPU and is using
I gb/1024mb RAM just as the Intel haxm. the

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm on Linux...  I have noticed however that launching the AVD is a pain from Android studio.  My work around is to launch the emulator (don't know how to do in windows) then run project from Android Studio interface  which is 10 icons from the aforementioned "?" icon and select from device chooser the running device.  Also the built in emulator is a pain....  Might be better for you if you connect your android device through usb and run  your apps directly through it.  For more info click [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html)

Comment: well, I'm trying to use the emulator on the useful since I'm mostly using my phone for other things. I followed the steps your link suggested and created a new avd device using using Google's android 6.0 x86 system image. I kept the RAM at 1 GB, and still the emulator window is not appearing.

Comment: Did you set up your device(real phone) with developer options?  Note: On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden by default. To make it available, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options.

Comment: After you enable your device it should be as simple as running your app and selecting your phone to run project.  If your phone is unlocked you'll get a notification saying "Allow USB debugging?".  You click OK then the app will load on your phone.  Furthermore the app will stay on your phone even after you disconnect from your computer.  Be aware that old data cables can  make your life hell...

Answer (score 0):

finally, I did it by unchecking the emulated performance from Use Host GPU to Store a snapshot for faster startup, and that worked fine..
. at least for now.
I also downgraded the API from API 23 to API 15. Everything now seems to be OK.